Error Implementing Lifecycle Hooks for Password Hashing with Sequelize-Typescript
I am working on a Node.js project using Sequelize-Typescript, and I'm trying to hash user passwords using lifecycle hooks (BeforeCreate and BeforeUpdate). However, I encounter an error related to how I'm importing or exporting my models.
Error:
Error: No default export defined for file "user.model" or export does not satisfy filename.

enter image description here
Code:
import { Table, Column, Model, PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, BeforeCreate, BeforeUpdate } from 'sequelize-typescript';
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
import { serverConfig } from '../config';
import { DataTypes } from 'sequelize';

@Table({ paranoid: true, timestamps: true })
export default class User extends Model<User> {
    @PrimaryKey
    @AutoIncrement
    @Column
    id!: number;

    @Column({
        type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
        allowNull: true,
    })
    email!: string;

    @Column({
        type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
        allowNull: true,
    })
    password!: string;

    @Column({
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true,
        defaultValue: 1,
    })
    status!: number;

    @BeforeCreate
    public static async hash(instance: User) {
        instance.password = await bcrypt.hash(instance.password, serverConfig.SALT);
    }

    @BeforeUpdate
    static async updatePassword(instance: User) {
        if (instance.changed('password')) {
            instance.password = await bcrypt.hash(instance.password, serverConfig.SALT);
        }
    }
}

I want to use sequelize lifecycle method to hash the password and along with some other validation.

how are you importing this class? if you're doing import { User } from './user.model' it won't work because the default exports aren't named. which means the import should be import * as User from './user.model'

import User  from '../models/User.model';
But how come it's working fine if I remove lifecycle hooks (@BeforeUpdate, @BeforeCreate)?

maybe this can help: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-typescript/issues/525
